# How to pass the Basic Auth while calling GETMAP request on GeoServer using OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

How can I pass the GeoServer credentials while adding an layer using WMS. When I am doing GETMAP request I am getting the error in Chrome

> [Deprecation] Subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials (e.g. `https://user:pass@host/`) are blocked. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856 for more details.

And When I tried in Firefox I am getting ERROR Code 403. So that is very clear that I can't pass the credentials in the URL while calling GETMAP Request. My code is:

```
function loadCustomURL() {
            var url = "https://user:pass@securewms.url.com:8443/geoserver/ows?service=wms&request=getmap&version=1.1.0&layers=some_layer&srs=epsg:3857&bbox=some_bbox&format=image/png&width=500&height=600"
            var source = new ol.source.TileWMS({ 
                url:url,
                serverType: 'geoserver',
                params: {
                    'LAYERS': '2-0',
                    'TILED': true
                }
            })

            source.on("tileloadstart",  function () {
                $('.message').html("Drawing..");
            })
            source.on("tileloadend",  function () {
                $('.message').html("");
            })
            source.on("tileloaderror",  function () {
                $('.message').html("Error Please try again");
            })
            var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
                source:  source
            });
            map.addLayer(layer);
        }
```

For GETCapablities when I had called I am getting its blocked because of CORS Policy
My code:

```
function WMSLayerCall() {
            var parser = new ol.format.WMSCapabilities();
            fetch('https://user:pass@securewms.url.com:8443/geoserver/ows?service=wms&request=GetCapabilities').then(function(response) {
                return response.text();
            }).then(function(text) {
                var result = parser.read(text);
                console.log(result);
                var extent = result.Capability.Layer.Layer.find(l => l.Name === '9').EX_GeographicBoundingBox;
                console.log(extent);
                //map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());
                var water_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                    url:"url",
                    serverType: 'mapserver',
                    srs: 'EPSG:4326',
                    bbox: extent,
                    format : 'image/png',
                    params: {
                        'LAYERS': "9",
                        'TILED': true
                    }
                })
            });
            map.addLayer(water_layer);
            });
        }
```

So how can I pas the credentials for a GETMAP request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a tileLoadFunction to load the tile via xhr with an Authorization header.  See [https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Tile.html#~LoadFunction](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Tile.html#%7ELoadFunction)

```
        var source = new ol.source.TileWMS({ 
            url:url,
            serverType: 'geoserver',
            params: {
                'LAYERS': '2-0',
                'TILED': true
            },
            tileLoadFunction: function (tile, src) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.responseType = 'blob';
                xhr.open('GET', src);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + window.btoa('username' + ":" + 'password'));
                xhr.onload = function() {
                    if (this.response) {
                        var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
                        tile.getImage().onload = function() {
                            URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
                        };
                        tile.getImage().src = objectUrl;
                    } else {
                        tile.setState(3);
                    }
                };
                xhr.onerror = function() {
                    tile.setState(3);
                };
                xhr.send();
            }
        })
```

Comment: I have implemented this method but now I am getting CORS Policy error

Comment: Have you removed `user:pass@` from the wms url?

Comment: yes I have removed that.

Comment: The server will need to enable CORS https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/container.html  If you don't have admin access you will need to use a proxy to bypass CORS.

Comment: for years, I didn't know this is possible for Openlayers 3.8.2 to be able to pass basic header for WMS GetMap requests.